# Google Hangout / Meet not working with ethernet cable on Macbook 2020

Tags: macos, google-hangouts, google-meet

When I joined Google Meet or Google Hangout with my new Macbook, I only saw the participants as black screens. Nobody could hear or see me. I tried Chrome, Safari, OSX Permissions, ...

Luckily a friend had the same problem and told me to unplug my ethernet cable and try wifi. That worked indeed.

Can anybody tell me how I can get this working with my ethernet cable?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the IPv6 configuration to `Link-local only` under the settings of the network adapter seems to solve this issue.

I am connected using a cable with Wi-Fi turned off.

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252111024?answerId=254255249022#254255249022

Answer (score 0):

Under your Mac settings > Network > [choose your adapter from the list] > Advanced > TCP/IP > Configure IPv6: change this from `automatic` to `link-local only`. This solved the issue for me.